# Right way to return from model to controller

Tags: php

I am sorry for asking this type of question but I'm getting really frustrated by this situation

This is my controller

```
public function changeName_PUT() { 
    header('Content-Type: application/json');

    $return = \Models\User::getCurrent()->changeName(Input::data());

    return json_encode($return);
}
```

And this is my model

```
public function changeName($data){
    $rules = array( ... );
    $messages = array( ... );

    $valid = Input::validate($data, $rules, $messages);

    if($valid === true){
        return $this->putIntoDb(array('name' => $data['name'])) ? 'Namechanged successfully.' : 'An error occurred.';
    }else{
        return $valid->getMessage();
    }
}
```

My problem is that no matter whether the model succeeds or fails there is always a string returned, so in the controller I cannot determine if the name was changed or not. If I return only `true` or `false` then in the controller, if something failed, I wouldn't know what it was. My other option is to return arrays from the model like `array('error', 'message')` but that looks so ugly and gives me the feeling that I'm doing it wrong. Can you point me the right way?

Comment: Throw an exception from the model or add an optional [byref](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php) parameter called `&$message` to the `changeName` function on the model? Better to throw an exception IMHO.

Comment: This is hardly about MVC at all. It's simply about how to properly return error states from a *function*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have different approaches :

- Simple version : If you insert, return the inserted_id|false. If you delete, return true|false. If you update, return true|false. If you select, return array|string|false.
- Class version : You return true or false (except for select which returns the queried string|array). And you store in a class variable the error messages so that you can do something like :

  ```
  $success = $model->query('blabla');
  if (!$success)
      print_r($model->getMessages());
  ```
- Object version : Same as the simple version, except that you return the database object on a successful select or update query (else false).
- Exception version : Same as object version, but instead of returning false, you throw an error that describes the problem.

Now, if you look at common frameworks you will see that CodeIgniter uses the object version, Phalcon uses the class version, Zend uses the exception version.
There is no "best-way", just use a method and stick with it for all your models.

(Just do not return a string that explains the error on a failed query!)

Answer (score 1):

Model layer should not be sending data to the controllers at all.

In the MVC architectural pattern the controllers are responsible for altering the state of model layer. And that's it. View instances then pull what information they need from said model layer.

If, because of controller's alterations, an error state is triggered in the model layer, then controller does not care about it. It is only important to the view, which, based on whether an error happened, might pick a different set of templates for assembly of response.

> <sub>**P.S.:** the HTTP headers are part of response. So, why are your "controllers" generating a response? It's basically no different from putting an **echo** there.</sub>

Comment: In the current example, how am I supposed to know what error occurred then?

Comment: And generally, isn't that the purpose of the model, to fetch data for the controller?

Comment: No. It's not. Also, model is a layer and **not a class**. Also, what you are talking about is a clear violation of the [Law of Demeter](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?LawOfDemeter).

Comment: I'm being greatly confused by this answer. Everywhere I read about MVC people are saying that the model retrieves data, doesn't care who's asking for it, the view displays data, doesn't care where it came from, and the controller glues it all together. All of the sudden I read this? Please elaborate! Regarding to your 'P.S.": where am I supposed to put this header? If my current controller returns `JSON`, but that may not be the case of another controller which uses the same model?

Comment: @php_nub_qq The model is a layer.

Comment: @Jimbo what is that supposed to mean

Comment: The MODEL is a LAYER within MVC. It is **not** a single object. There is no such thing as a "User Model", for example. You may have a User entity within the model layer. Extra clarification.